# How to prevent modal dialog form to close after pressing OK?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a  (login) form that use it as modal like this (parent form code):

```
using (var login = new Login())
{
     login.ShowDialog();
}
```

I do some checks on opened modal dialog and I want that it not close on pressing OK button if user name and password was wrong.

My login:

```
private void goSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var loggedInCustomer =LoginController.signIn(usernameBox.Text, passwordBox.Text);
     if (loggedInCustomer == null)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password! :( ", "Wrong!");
     }
     else
         Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the button (goSignIn) DialogResult property. If it's set, it automatically close the form.

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than None, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events. The form's DialogResult property is then set to the DialogResult of the button when the button is clicked.

[MSDN Button.DialogResult  Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've set the `DialogResult` of `goSignIn` button to some value(probably `DialogResult.OK`), remove that line, everything should work fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call close then

```
private void goSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var loggedInCustomer =LoginController.signIn(usernameBox.Text, passwordBox.Text);
  if (loggedInCustomer == null)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password! :( ", "Wrong!");
  }
  else
  {
     Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have forgotten to add `else`; but again it close modal form