# C# Cancel click event if conditions are not met

Tags: c#, buttonclick

I am writing a program in windows forms where I have a listbox in Form1 as well as a button. When pressing the button Form2 opens where I have some textboxes that will add things to a list. This list is then transferred to Form1 and printed in the listbox when the user presses OK.

However, I would like to have a condition that ensures that the list has both a name and that it isn't empty. I have a method called CheckValuesOK() in Form2, and am using that one to check the values in Form1 before printing them. The appropriate messageboxes are displayed if everything is not filled out properly, but Form2 still closes. How can I avoid this?

It currently looks like this in Form1:

```
            FoodItemForm foodItemForm = new FoodItemForm();
            if(foodItemForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (foodItemForm.CheckInputOK())
                {
                    lbxFoodItems.Items.Add(foodItemForm.FItem.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799832/how-to-prevent-modal-dialog-form-to-close-after-pressing-ok

Comment: Well, yes, however, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to implement that since if I add the if-statement to the btnOK-click event instead and then add btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.None, Form2 still closes.

Comment: did u read the documentation what was linked in the answer of the duplicate question?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Button_DialogResult
you have to set it to a value other than OK before you call the Show method

Comment: I did and turns out I needed a break from the code to make more sense of it. Thanks!